# XCode - how to set rendering mode of an image set in xcassets

Tags: xcode, xcasset

As pointed out here in @Anthony Mattox (and many other posts), to set the rendering mode of an image set in `Assets.xcassets`, just simply select that image and pick `Template Image` option in `Render As` of `Attributes Inspector`.

How come do I always see `No Selection` in my `Attributes Inspector` no matter what image I choose: image set, or sub-images.

[image: <code>No Selection</code> in <code>Attributes Inspector</code>]

What should I do in order to display the options in `Attributes Inspector` for a selected image?

My XCode: Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was a bug related to Xcode tabs. Closed all tabs and the inspector started working properly.

Note that restarting Xcode didn't fix the issue until I reset the tabs.